# Array index seems to slide when writing values

Tags: c++

I have a `Npp8u * image = new Npp8u[nWidth * nHeight];` array that stores grayscale image values. I defined Npp8u as `typedef unsigned char Npp8u;`. The problem occurs when I try to subtract the lowest image value from ever pixel.

I use this function to do the subtraction.

```
void SubtractValue(Npp8u * image, int width, int height, Npp8u value){
    int iValue = value;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
            int indexVal = (image[i*width + j]);
            int newVal = indexVal - iValue;
            image[i*width + j] = (Npp8u) newVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Result of this function is quite strange. I use Lena Image to test, this is the original image. [image]

If the value is 85 I get the following image
[image]

Note: The original image is .pgm

Reading procedure:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nHeight; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < nWidth; ++j)
        image[i*nWidth + j] = fgetc(fInput);
```

Writing procedure:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nHeight; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < nWidth; ++j)
        fputc(image[i*nWidth + j], fOutput);
```

Update: The problem occurs if the pixel has the value 10, which is new line feed.

Comment: what happens when you read and write the image without changing anything?

Comment: @Wimmel I get the same image, and also if I subtract 10 ( value is 10), there is no sliding in the pixels.

Comment: Just a wild guess; the [format description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example) specifies the maximum white value in the header. If you substract 85 from a number which is less then 85, the number will wrap around and the result will be a high white value. Maybe it is discarded if it is larger then the max value in the header.

Comment: @Wimmel, that was my first guess too. Thus, I added `    if (newVal > 255)
    newVal = 255;
   if (newVal < 0)
    newVal = 0;`. However, with value being 80 these if statements were always false. Btw, the minimum value of this image is 92. I am not sure if this is an unsigned problem.

Comment: @Hakes - I am not familiar with your image format, but with most formats, the file needs to be processed in "binary" mode.  If this is the case for your format, did you open the file as "wb" and/or "rb"?  I mention this, since you say you had an issue with 10 (carriage return).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, that solved the problem, I opened the file as "w+". Changing to "wb" solved the problem.

Comment: @Hakes - Posted the answer.  Please upvote if this has solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that character 10 was causing the issue, one would suspect that the image format you're reading/writing needs to processed in "binary" file mode, so that ASCII 10 is not treated as a line feed.

Therefore make sure that file is opened in binary mode (for `fopen` use the `"rb"` or `"wb"` flags, depending on whether you're reading or writing).